# Window parent not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a parent page and a child page.
By using window.opener.parent property,I am able to read the parent page content and display it in the child page.(There is a PREVIEW button on parent page,on click of which the child page opens up as a popup and displays the content of parent page controls.)

This functionality was working fine in IE7/Mozilla/IE6 but I am unable to locate why its not workin with IE8. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The window name may be invalid, as IE8 is very picky about it. Verify that the window name does not contain any space characters. For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx